# Can I change my Schengen Itinerary after refusal for the re-application?

Tags: schengen-visas

Last week, my Schengen application via France was refused. Can I reapply immediately to a different embassy (Greece) with a shorter itinerary? I originally applied for 24 days and I want to shorten in to 14 days. Should I also change the submitted letter of approved dates of leave? I will also be submitting additional documents I failed to attach on my last application like properties I owned.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But keep in mind that a steady, well-documented **income** is more important than the **assets** you own.

- You can reapply immediately, at the same or a different embassy. Where you make your application depends on your itinerary. The Greek officials will see your visa history, of course.
- It might make sense to write a *short* paragraph in a cover letter to explain that you have been refused before because *you* did not submit enough documents, and that your itinerary changed accordingly.
- Getting a visa for 14 days will not be easier than getting a visa for 24 days.